# Creating and adding to a session

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a shopping cart and having some trouble adding the first item to it. The shopping cart code is below:

```
switch($action) { //decide what to do 

    case "add":

        $_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
    break;

    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID]--; //remove one from the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID]); //if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID]); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart. 
    break;

    case "nothing":
    break;
}
```

When I add an item for the first time (the first one added to the basket) it gives me these errors

```
Notice: Undefined index: cart in H:\STUDENT\S0190204\GGJ\Basket.php on line 59 Notice: Undefined index: 1 in H:\STUDENT\S0190204\GGJ\Basket.php on line 59
```

Comment: did you forgot `session_start()` ?

Comment: No sessions_start() is there

Comment: can you print var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: You can't ++ on a variable that's not yet set. You must initialize it with a value beforehand if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 case "add":
 if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID])){
  $_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID]=0;
 }
  $_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID]++;
  break;
```

This should work because when you are gonna try to increment first time `$_SESSION['cart'][$item_ID]` it is not set

see this

`$_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID]++` is equvivalent to

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID] = $_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID] + 1;
```

in the above expression `$_SESSION['cart'][$Item_ID]` is undefined (on right-hand side of assignment)